# Split string by separators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm try to split text from string, but I can't.

I have `1;2 | 2;4`, for example in my string, and I want to:

`['1;2', '|', '2;4']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> '1;2 | 2;4'.partition("|")
('1;2 ', '|', ' 2;4')
```